# How do I check if and why my comments are deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I wrote a comment under my answer here https://law.stackexchange.com/a/45200/10872

I'm not sure why its gone. Was it deleted, and by who? Is there a moderation log that shows this?

The comment itself was, to my knowledge, not irrelevant or inappropriate in the circumstances so I am not sure why its not there anymore.

To make sure this question doesn't merge as a duplicate of "why was my comment deleted" etc. I am specifically asking: how can I check if my comment has been deleted by moderation action?

Comment: I also commented regarding the disconnect between the posters questiion and stated identity. Mine was also deleted.

Answer (score 3):

> I am specifically asking: how can I check if my comment has been deleted by moderation action?

You cannot check if and why your comments are deleted (unless you create a meta post asking about it or ping mods in chat). I know, that sucks. [Same issue with questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179). Same issue with answers. This isn't specific to https://law.meta.stackexchange.com but all Stack Exchange websites.

Answer (score 0):

### Comments do not last

Please read the comment [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) info and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) Stack Exchange meta question. Relevantly:

> Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
>
> Comments are **disposable**: unlike posts, there's no public revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.

If you want to say something permanent, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) it into the post. Even if its not yours.

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is **encouraged**!

### Why they get deleted

Because a mod thinks they should be - essentially, the mod is of the opinion that they have served their purpose or have no purpose or they break the rules. This may be in response to a flag or it may be just because a mod was passing by.

In theory at least, all comments should eventually be deleted. Related [How to deal with comments?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-deal-with-comments)

### How can you check?

**Easy, if you didn’t delete it a moderator did.**

### If you really want to know about a particular comment

You can flag the post and ask a moderator to tell you. If the comment is still accessible, a mod can see who deleted it - only the particular mod who deleted it could tell you why.

Comment: To clarify: by "we", do you mean only moderators are able to see how a comment was deleted, or can I as a regular user do so as well?

Comment: I do not see any flags raised on my profile. Does this mean my comment was deleted without being flagged? If so, how can I determine who deleted my comment and why. It is important for me to know why a comment was deleted so that I can prevent making the same kind of comment in the future

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks There’s nothing wrong with having comments deleted - it’s to be expected.

Comment: Its wrong when they are deleted for a wrongful reason. The link you provided on stack exchange's policy on comment deletion clearly states:"Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion". Therefore, if none of these criteria are met, then the comment may logically stand until the eventual time the criteria is met.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks sure. I didn’t delete this particular comment but I believe that the last criteria was met - the issue raised had been addressed by a different comment on the question which is still there and is the more appropriate place for it.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks - I am not aware of any way you can look at your profile and figure out that a flag was raised about something you posted or commented.  There is a way of looking at the response to flags you raised -- but that is different.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157344/287826.  You can look at your flagging history on a particular site and perhaps there will be a moderator response to a flag you raised on a post (asking why your comment was removed).